# artdarek oAuth Facebook doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth

My Code given below:

```
Route::get('/facebook', 'ApiUserController@socialConnect');

public function socialConnect()
    {

    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );

        $message = 'Your unique facebook user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        echo $message. "<br/>";

        //Var_dump
        //display whole array().
        dd($result);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }

}
```

> Error : Method [getData] does not exist on Redirect.

It does always bring this error while invoking http://localhost:8000/v1/facebook even though I added the url http://localhost:8000/v1/facebook in Valid OAuth redirect URIs

Please suggest the same

```
$duration = Benchmarking::end('application');
    $duration = ($duration * 1000) . 'ms';

    Log::info($response->getStatusCode() . ' ' . $request->path() . ' :: ' . $duration);

if (!Config::get('app.debug'))
{
    return $response;
}

$data = $response->getData();

if (is_array($data)) {
    return $response;
}

$data->queryLog = DB::getQueryLog();
$data->responseTime = $duration;

$response->setData($data);

return $response;
```

This filter is creating problem what can we fixed it out

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update the response in json format works fine

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple package for social auth: https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.